# Another square-root simplification problem

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In a certain sequence of computations, sometimes I'll get an expression of a form such as

```
Sqrt[u^4 + 4 u^6]
```

which it is necessary to have converted "automatically", for `u > 0` to:

```
u^2 Sqrt[1 + 4 u^2]
```

The exact square-root to be converted will not always be the same, e.g,, it might be `Sqrt[u^6 + 5 u^9]`.

I've tried `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, and `PowerExpand`, all including `Assumptions -> u > 0`, to no avail.

I note that, by contrast,

```
Simplify[Sqrt[u^2 + 5 u^3], u > 0]
```

does yield the desired `u Sort[1 + 5 u]`.

How can this be done?

I'd like to avoid *too* special a replacement rule!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like this using [`Factor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html) to help grease the wheels:

```
expr = Sqrt[u^4 + 4 u^6];
PowerExpand[Factor[expr]]
(* u^2 Sqrt[1 + 4 u^2] *)
```

I think this will work in any of your cases.

```
expr = Sqrt[u^6 + 4 u^9]    
PowerExpand[Factor[expr]]
(* u^3 Sqrt[1 + 4 u^3] *)
```

Comment: That does it, thanks! (At least so far on expressions I've encountered in this context.)